# Phone unintentionally pairing to Subaru Bluetooth even when off

Tags: subaru, bluetooth

Twice in the last day when making a call from my house, my phone has automatically paired to my car, which is turned off and parked outside.

Why is this happening and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the car have an aftermarket head unit in it?

Comment: Have you turned off bluetooth on the phone...

Comment: Does the Subaru allow you to unlock the doors, start the vehicle etc via your phone?